# Unlimit Console Output in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any downside to disabling the 'Limit Console Output' option in Eclipse?

Anything that can potentially slow down (or even crash) as the console continues to accumulate data?

I would like to consider using this as an alternative for saving every printout in a log file.

If there is no downside, then why is it enabled by default (and moreover, why does this feature exist in the first place)?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that everything is held in memory so you will eventually run out of heap space.

Comment: JVM Heap? Does that mean my that my program (which is a JVM process) will crash? Because to my understanding, the Eclipse is a different process in the system.

Comment: Eclipse is also a Java program, so it means Eclipse might crash or start behaving weirdly. Believe me, I know what happens when Eclipse runs out of memory - it starts behaving really weirdly.